# Area swept by a moving shape

Tags: 2d, procedural-generation

I have a shape (in a pinch it could be reduced to a rectangle) that is moving along a bezier spline segment and rotating to align with the direction of movement. I need to generate a mesh for the area touched by this rectangle. All strictly in 2D.

Currently I draw the shape at fixed intervals and then connect the corners of "neighboring" instances. Basically like an extrusion, but staying in the plane. This obviously leads to a massively self-intersecting mesh with tons of overdraw and unecessary triangles. I can just about have it colored with a constant color and get alpha working using the stencil buffer, but anything involving texture coordinates (gradients, textures, etc) leads to visible artifacts.

Is there a nice algorithm to do this smarter and better? Both my brain and my google-fu fail me.